# Remote control of iPad pro from another touchscreen display

Tags: ipad, remote-control

With AirServer I am able to display my iPad screen on another device.
Now, I would like to know what are the possible solutions to have a remote control of my iPad.

Unfortunately, Teamviewer or VNC are not allowing such thing.

Someone has an idea ?

Regards,

Kelson

Comment: Though I have no experience with this specifically, from what I have seen it is not possible for live remote control. Teamviewer has a method for this but it just sends screen captures back and it does not look like it is a true remote control software like ARD or RDP.

Comment: There is no way to actually control the device if it's on stock iOS. Are you fine with a jailbreak solution.

Comment: Thanks for yours answers. Unfornately, I cannot go on a jailbreak solution..

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Apple does not allow remotely controlling an iOS device, but if you are jailbroken, you can use the Veency tweak:

1. Open Cydia to search for and install Veency.
2. Respring when prompted.
3. Go to Settings > Veency and choose the settings you want.
4. Figure out your IP address by going to Settings > Wifi > click the "i" next to your currently connected network and the IP address should be listed there.
5. Open up a VNC client on your computer and connect to your device by inputting the IP address when prompted.

Comment: Hi @abc, I will give a try on your solution for a personal test. However, I found an article on Extensify which allow to use tweak without jailbreaking, have you ever play with ? https://9to5mac.com/2016/02/27/extensify-tweak-store-no-jailbreak-needed/

Comment: The article is misleading, you can only tweak app store apps with extensify.